# How to throw an exception with a std::unique_ptr member variable

Tags: c++, exception, move, unique-ptr

I want to do something like this:

```
class Exception : public std::exception {
    std::unique_ptr<Data> data;
public:
    Exception(std::unique_ptr<Data> d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Data> getData() { return std::move(data); }
};

std::unique_ptr<Data> someFunction()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Data> data(new Data);
    if (error)
        throw Exception(std::move(data));
    else
        return data;
}

std::unique_ptr<Data> someOtherFunction()
{
    try
    {
        return someFunction();
    }
    catch (Exception &e)
    {
        if (ignore_errors)
            return e.getData();
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

But this does not compile, because the `Exception` class is not copyable.

One way to make it copyable is to implement it as:

```
class Exception : public std::exception {
    std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Data> > data;
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Data> d) : data(new std::unique_ptr<Data>(std::move(d))) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Data> getData() { return std::move(*data); }
};
```

But I feel like having a `shared_ptr` to a `unique_ptr` is pretty convoluted. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about `catch (const Exception &e)` or `catch (Exception &&e)`? Makes more sense IMO anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ First of all, it's not the catching that's the problem, it's the throwing. Second of all, it can't be `const`, because returning the `unique_ptr` transfers ownership and modifies its value (`getData` is not `const` for a reason).

Comment: Use moving (as I've edited my comment)? `throw` just uses the specified type from the `catch` clause.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is that allowed? But again, it's the throwing that doesn't compile, not the catching.

Comment: After boiling your example down to a [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8615fa253bf5052), I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see that in Coliru, if you use my original `catch (Exception &e)`, then it does compile. But in MSVS 2010, it does not... Perhaps this has to do with the incomplete implementation of C++11 back in 2010.

Comment: Could well be. VS2010 didn't implement the c++11 standard properly. Though changing the code compiles, it results in a [core dump](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f03c374d4a0f575a).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's because the exception is thrown. Change `ignore_error` to true and see it runs fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Here's a more functional example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b2c465bfbae5e9c). Try it with various values of `error` and `ignore_error`.

Comment: I made my values for `error` and `ignore_error` consciously, as these can be dtermined at compile time. If you have a different situation, elaborate your question please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I had in mind that those values are determined at runtime depending on certain conditions and things: `error` is if an actual error occurs, and `ignore_error` is if the error can safely be ignored.